# I can't find the HDRI that i need

Tags: light, lighting, hdri

I want to light my scene with a HDRI but I can't find the one that I want.
I need a uniform white light for an presentation image.

I just want to show my model as it really looks.
I found one but it looks ok only in front view(if i rotate thee view it looks darker)I want a uniform light from on every part of the model.:[image]. 
if i turn the view :
[image]

Comment: If you want uniform white, you can just set the world background to white and set the strength to whatever suits your needs. Otherwise for actual HDRIs images https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/category/?c=all

Comment: If i use the world background my model looks very flal(even if i used an normal map for the details)

Comment: Well yes, a flat uniform lighting all around creates a flat and uniform look. I suggest you download one of the studio HDRIs from the link I've posted and setup the background like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147090/how-can-i-render-the-reflections-i-see-in-the-look-dev-viewport-in-blender-2-8/147093#147093

Comment: Alternatively you can also activate Ambient Occlusion in the World tab to make it a bit less flat.

Comment: Thanks !I will try :)

Comment: If you add an example image for the lighting you're look for we can perhaps make some recommendations.

Comment: You can use a generic studio hdri inside a simple white box. It should give you good reflections but fewer background pixels. Alternatively, you could just turn the background off in Render Settings > Film > Transparent.